# How to make api's in swagger ui authenticated in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have written a spring boot application using **Oauth2**(Password flow)
I want the API's in swagger UI to be accessible without the access token. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should permit Swagger-Ui related paths in order to do that inside your security config please permit these paths
                       `.antMatchers(
                        "/v2/api-docs",
                        "/swagger-resources",
                        "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui",
                        "/swagger-resources/configuration/security")
                        .permitAll()`